# Can we distribute the TestNG tests in Selenium Grid when running the tests in parallel but in the same browser

Tags: automated-tests, testng, selenium-grid2

Problem Statement:
i have 100 test cases which i am willing to run using Selenium Grid 2 but only in Chrome using two Nodes.
Is it possible to divide the test cases 50 per system in Grid.
Because when i run the 100 Test Cases in parallel selenium runs all the test cases in both the systems and the tests fail(at times). Though i am using ThreadLocal to create the WebDriver Instance.Like you can see below the same test runs on both the nodes, but what i want the tests to not repeat itself and run parallely on the same browser.

```
    10:40:25,770  INFO - Executing:- verifyFooterItemsIsDisplayed
    10:40:25,770  INFO - Executing:- verifyFooterItemsIsDisplayed
```

Answer (score 0):

was able to do it with parallel="classes" and adding the classes to the testNG.xml file.